# Adding a formula into Excel cell from vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet labeled my_new_name and want to put in a formula, having looked at other stack overflow threads i have come up with the following:

```
Set wsDest = Sheets("my_new_name")
wsDest.Range("J2").Formula = "=RIGHT(K2,2)&" / "&MID(K2,5,2)&" / "&LEFT(K2,4)"
wsDest.Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J")
```

However this doesn't work and the error comes up with a 'type mismatch'

Any help would be great

Comment: you need to specify the last column on column J, `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J")` should be for example `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1000)`

Comment: The issue is in your formula. I don't know what's in `Range("J2")`, but that formula you're trying to set is incorrect either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the Formula output you're after reads as `=RIGHT(K2,2)&"/"&MID(K2,5,2)&"/"&LEFT(K2,4)`, you'll have to escape the double quotes in your VBA line.

`wsDest.Range("J2").Formula = "=RIGHT(K2,2)&" / "&MID(K2,5,2)&" / "&LEFT(K2,4)"` (throws type mismatch)

Should be:

`wsDest.Range("J2").Formula = "=RIGHT(K2,2)&"" / ""&MID(K2,5,2)&"" / ""&LEFT(K2,4)"` (doesn't error)

**Edit:**
Also, as per comment section you'll need to specify the end row afterwards `(J2:J####)` - where ### is a row number.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what the loogic is behind this as I have another formula that i'm trying to work on too.  "=DATEDIF(B2,J2,"d")"

Comment: Whenever you have a string that should include the "-character, you'll have to escape it with another "-character, otherwise VBA will interpret it as the end of the string. Example: `string = "This is a string"`, `string = "This is a string that includes a " character"` (this will error, since the string ends at the space after a) and `string = "This is a string that includes a "" character"` (will print as: 'This is a string that includes a " character').

Comment: As to "=DATEDIF" - you should write `Formula = "=DATEDIF(B2,J2,""d"")"`